# Como identificar um número (por extenso) em uma frase

Tags: javascript, node.js

Preciso de um script para identificar um número em uma frase.
Ex:

"**Two** weeks ago" -> numero = 2

Pode ser até por substituição mesmo. Assim:

se **str** conter **two**, replace("two", 2)

Tem algum módulo node que faça isso? Já procurei, mas só achei alguns que fazem o contrário ( numero -> extenso )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thiago, o que consegui foi uma função vinda do Python passada para javascript, como pode ver [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980087/javascript-words-to-numbers). Mas, é bastante funcional:

```js
var Small = {
  'zero': 0,
  'one': 1,
  'two': 2,
  'three': 3,
  'four': 4,
  'five': 5,
  'six': 6,
  'seven': 7,
  'eight': 8,
  'nine': 9,
  'ten': 10,
  'eleven': 11,
  'twelve': 12,
  'thirteen': 13,
  'fourteen': 14,
  'fifteen': 15,
  'sixteen': 16,
  'seventeen': 17,
  'eighteen': 18,
  'nineteen': 19,
  'twenty': 20,
  'thirty': 30,
  'forty': 40,
  'fifty': 50,
  'sixty': 60,
  'seventy': 70,
  'eighty': 80,
  'ninety': 90
};

var Magnitude = {
  'thousand': 1000,
  'million': 1000000,
  'billion': 1000000000,
  'trillion': 1000000000000,
  'quadrillion': 1000000000000000,
  'quintillion': 1000000000000000000,
  'sextillion': 1000000000000000000000,
  'septillion': 1000000000000000000000000,
  'octillion': 1000000000000000000000000000,
  'nonillion': 1000000000000000000000000000000,
  'decillion': 1000000000000000000000000000000000,
};

var a, n, g;

function text2num(s) {
  a = s.toString().split(/[\s-]+/);
  n = 0;
  g = 0;
  a.forEach(feach);
  return g + n;
}
function feach(w) {
  var x = Small[w];
  if (x != null) {
    g = g + x;
  } else if (w == "hundred") {
    g = g * 100;
  } else if (w == "and") {
    return;
  } else {
    x = Magnitude[w];
    if (x != null) {
      n = n + g * x
      g = 0;
    }
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML += text2num('five billion two million one hundred and fourteen thousand and sixty-nine');
```

A questão mais "complicada", no caso, é a substituição, pois capturar a sequência de palavras que podem ou não corresponder a um número seria um pouco mais trabalhoso. Mas você pode também usar um *marker*. No caso coloquei `$()`.

No exemplo a seguir, eu uso o marker em `one` e em `two` o que claramente não seria necessário já que são números pequenos, mas no caso do "five billion two million one hundred and fourteen thousand and sixty-nine", seria difícil reconhecê-lo em meio a outras palavras.

```js
var Small = {
  'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6, 'seven': 7, 'eight': 8, 'nine': 9, 'ten': 10, 'eleven': 11, 'twelve': 12, 'thirteen': 13, 'fourteen': 14, 'fifteen': 15, 'sixteen': 16, 'seventeen': 17, 'eighteen': 18, 'nineteen': 19, 'twenty': 20, 'thirty': 30, 'forty': 40, 'fifty': 50, 'sixty': 60, 'seventy': 70, 'eighty': 80, 'ninety': 90
};

var Magnitude = {
  'thousand': 1000, 'million': 1000000, 'billion': 1000000000, 'trillion': 1000000000000, 'quadrillion': 1000000000000000, 'quintillion': 1000000000000000000, 'sextillion': 1000000000000000000000, 'septillion': 1000000000000000000000000, 'octillion': 1000000000000000000000000000, 'nonillion': 1000000000000000000000000000000, 'decillion': 1000000000000000000000000000000000,
};

var a, n, g;

function text2num(s) {
  a = s.toString().split(/[\s-]+/);
  n = 0;
  g = 0;
  a.forEach(feach);
  return g + n;
}

function feach(w) {
  var x = Small[w];
  if (x != null) {
    g = g + x;
  } else if (w == "hundred") {
    g = g * 100;
  } else if (w == "and") {
    return;
  } else {
    x = Magnitude[w];
    if (x != null) {
      n = n + g * x
      g = 0;
    }
  }
}

var regex = /\$\([^$]+\)/g;
var text = document.querySelectorAll('p')[0].innerHTML;

text.match(regex).forEach(function(el, i) {
 el = el.replace(/(\(|\)|\$)/g, "");
  var re = new RegExp('\\$\\('+el+'\\)', 'g');
  text = text.replace(re, text2num(el))
})

document.body.innerHTML += "<br><br>";
document.body.innerHTML += text;
```

```html
<p>No $(two) objects can occupy the same place at $(one) time
  <p/>
```

### Versão sem o marker

Acho que consegui uma maneira de reconhecer o número em meio a outras palavras, sem a necessidade dos markers anteriores,  lhe peço que procure por possíveis erros. Dê uma olhada, criei a função "replaceToNum()", que recebe uma string qualquer como argumento e retorna a mesma string, porém com os números por extenso convertidos em algarismos numéricos:

```js
function replaceToNum(text) {
  var Small = { 'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6, 'seven': 7, 'eight': 8, 'nine': 9, 'ten': 10, 'eleven': 11, 'twelve': 12, 'thirteen': 13, 'fourteen': 14, 'fifteen': 15, 'sixteen': 16, 'seventeen': 17, 'eighteen': 18, 'nineteen': 19, 'twenty': 20, 'thirty': 30, 'forty': 40, 'fifty': 50, 'sixty': 60, 'seventy': 70, 'eighty': 80, 'ninety': 90 };
  var Magnitude = { 'thousand': 1000, 'million': 1000000, 'billion': 1000000000, 'trillion': 1000000000000, 'quadrillion': 1000000000000000, 'quintillion': 1000000000000000000, 'sextillion': 1000000000000000000000, 'septillion': 1000000000000000000000000, 'octillion': 1000000000000000000000000000, 'nonillion': 1000000000000000000000000000000, 'decillion': 1000000000000000000000000000000000 };
  var a, n, g;
  function text2num(s) {
    a = s.toString().split(/[\s-]+/); n = 0; g = 0;
    a.forEach(feach);
    return g + n;
  }
  function feach(w) {
    var x = Small[w];
    if (x != null) {
      g = g + x;
    } else if (w == "hundred") {
      g = g * 100;
    } else if (w == "and") {
      return;
    } else {
      x = Magnitude[w];
      if (x != null) {
        n = n + g * x
        g = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  var words = "(" + Object.keys(Magnitude).join('|') + "|and|hundred|" + Object.keys(Small).join('|') + ")+( |-)*" + "(" + Object.keys(Magnitude).join('|') + "|and|-|hundred| |" + Object.keys(Small).join('|') + ")*( |[.,^~`´])";
  var regex = new RegExp(words, 'gim');
  text = text.toString() + " ";
  text.match(regex).forEach(function(el, i) {
    text = text.replace(el.replace(/\s$/g, '').replace(/[.,^~`´]/g, ''), text2num(el.replace(/[.,^~`´]/g, '').toLowerCase()));
  })
  return text;
}
var text = "No two objects can occupy the same place one time. Bla bla bla five billion Two Million one hundred and fourteen thousand and sixty-nine. Four. Minha criatividade tá ZeRo";

document.body.innerHTML += "<br><br>";
document.body.innerHTML += replaceToNum(text);
```

Comment: Samir, testei a tua solução (https://jsfiddle.net/hdtqc12u/1/) e reparei que não aceita letra grande nos numeros nem mais que uma ocorrência por string. Não sei se é importante para o AP. De resto ++

Comment: @Sergio, acho que o problema está resolvido. Obrigado pelo adendo.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal!!

Answer (score 3):

Há uns tempos trabalhei nesta ideia num projeto onde precisava de filtrar idades de clientes num `<input>`. Depois acabei por mudar a abordagem e criar botões para receber numeros sem ter de os filtrar. Mas a ideia era esta:

```
var numbers = {
    en: ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety', 'hundred'],
    se: ['noll', 'ett', 'två', 'tre', 'fyra', 'fem', 'sex', 'sju', 'åtta', 'nio', 'tio', 'elva', 'tolv', 'tretton', 'fjorton', 'femton', 'sexton', 'sjutton', 'arton', 'nitton', 'tjugo', "trettio", "fyrtio", "femtio", "sextio", "sjuttio", "åttio", "nittio", "hundra"],
    de: ["null", "eins", "zwei", "drei", "vier", "fünf", "sechs", "sieben", "acht", "neun", "zehn", "elf", "zwölf", "dreizehn", "vierzehn", "fünfzehn", "sechzehn", "siebzehn", "achtzehn", "neunzehn", "zwanzig", "dreißig", "vierzig", "fünfzig", "sechzig", "siebzig", "achtzig", "neunzig", "hundert"],
    no: ["null", "en", "to", "tre", "fire", "fem", "seks", "sju", "åtte", "ni", "ti", "elleve", "tolv", "tretten", "fjorten", "femten", "seksten", "sytten", "atten", "nitten", "tyve", "tretti", "førti", "femti", "seksti", "sytti", "åtti", "nitti", "hundre"]
};
var mapper = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];

function findNumber(string) {
    var results = [];
    Object.keys(numbers).forEach(function(lang) {
        var nrs = numbers[lang];
        nrs.forEach(function(nr, i) {
            var rexep = new RegExp('[^\\w\\-]' + nr + '[^\\w\\-]|^' + nr + '[^\\w\\-]|[^\\w\\-]' + nr + '$|^' + nr + '$', 'gi');
            var match = string.match(rexep);
            if (match) {
                var mappedNumber = mapper[i];
                if (mappedNumber > 19) {
                    var customRegexp = new RegExp(match[0].trim() + '\\s\\w+', 'i');
                    var wholeNumber = string.match(customRegexp);
                    if (wholeNumber) mappedNumber = mappedNumber + results.pop();
                }
                results = results.concat(mappedNumber)
            }
        });
    });
    var more = string.match(/\d+/g) || [];
    return results.concat(more).map(Number);
};
```

Basicamente essa função compara texto de linguas diferentes e extrai os numeros. 
Um exemplo seria:

```
var testes = ['TWO WEEKS AGO', 'two weeks ago', 'I am thirty seven years old!', 'I was the the number five in my class! Now I am number one!'];
console.log(JSON.stringify(testes.map(findNumber))); // [[2],[2],[37],[1,5]]
```

Na altura não avancei mais com isto. Pode ser que te sirva como está, coisas que me lembro queria fazer:

- respeitar a ordem encontrada no resultado
- permitir ordens superiores a 100 (a lógica podia ser com `Math.floor(nr / 100)` e procurar as *N* palavras seguintes)
- fazer o filtro da lingua primeiro para evitar casos onde palavras de outras linguas fazem match.

Se quiseres usar podes ver um exemplo live aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/hdtqc12u/

Comment: Ótima opção. Fazer o filtro da língua seria bem interessante rsrs.