# Como converter um número em forma de string em número em forma de int no python?

Tags: python

Por exemplo, tenho uma variável chamada: 'Numero oitentaenove' e quero transformar essa variável em: 'Numero 89'. De que forma posso fazer isso?

```
var = input()
if 'zero' in var:
    var = var.replace('zero','0')
if 'um' in var:
    var = var.replace('um','1')
if 'dois' in var:
    var = var.replace('dois','2')
if 'três' in var:
    var = var.replace('três','3')   
if 'quatro' in var:
    var = var.replace('quatro','4')
if 'cinco' in var:
    var = var.replace('cinco','5')
if 'seis' in var:
    var = var.replace('seis','6')
if 'sete' in var:
    var = var.replace('sete','7')
if 'oito' in var:
    var = var.replace('oito','8')
if 'nove' in var:
    var = var.replace('nove','9')
    
print(var)
```

Estive fazendo algo dessa forma mas obviamente não deu certo.

Comment: Talvez ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142388/112052 (não é em Python, mas dá pra ter uma ideia geral)

Answer (score -2):

Se tem muitos numeros que vc quer tratar isso parece bem inprodutivo já que vai ter que criar uma condição para cada numero, talvez vc tenha que repensar o seu código.

Use o `elif` ao invés de vários `if` e na última opção use o `else`, a não ser que vc queira que a variável seja verificada por todos os `if`

Algo assim funciona...

````
if 'zero' in var:
    n = 'numero'
    v = n + ' 0'
elif 'um' in var:
    n = 'numero'
    v = n + ' 1'
else:
    v = 'algo deu errado'
```
````